# Neovim LSP customization - are there downsides with setting LSP for to many languages?

Tags: neovim, vim-plugin

I recently took a deep dive into Neovim and quite enjoy my journey so far. Thing is, I am currently working on a lot of different projects with different techstacks simultaneously, so I'm in need for LSP for a broad amount of languages. The Neovim configurations I spotted so far, really don't have that much technology mixed together - therefore I would like to know, if it is bad to setup LSP for a lot of languages at the same time...? Does this have disadvantages or is it no good practice to use lots of LSPs? I need it for the classic Webstack, Go, Rust and so on.

Thanks in advance!

Trying to use multilanguage LSP, but didn't find configs setup like that so far - bad practice or any downsides?

Comment: Should not be a problem IMO. I have 5 lsp providers configured (dotnet, bash, powershell, lua and python) so far - no problems. I've disabled autostart and launch lsp server only when it is needed.